Entity Framework doesn't allow null value in nullable int
I have a stored procedure which returns a simple table.
I call it using Entity Framework like this:
var dbResult = await MyTypeResult.FromSqlRaw(
    "EXEC MyStoredProcedure @myVar",
    db_myVar
).ToListAsync();

where the MyTypeResult variable is of type DbSet<MyTypeResult>.
This is that class:
public class MyTypeResult
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    // <more properties...>
}

At runtime it throws the following error:

An error occurred while reading a database value for property 'MyTypeResult.Id'.
The expected type was 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' but the actual value was null.

Why do I get this error?
I am aware and expecting null values to be returned, and I have marked the Id property as nullable, but it's apparently not sufficient.

Is this database code first or are you using scaffold to create the data model?

@Byrd It's a project initially scaffolded from a database first approach.

That's strange. This could be an OnModelCreating event problem? Do you have an OnModelCreating event or anything that was autogenerated with FluentAPI in your DbContext? You may try using data annotations to explicitly call the Column TypeName to a nullable int32 then add the migration and update the database.
